# No provider for AnimationEngine

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material2

I just updated my dependencies to the latest

```
"@angular/animations": "4.4.1",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "4.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.1",
"@angular/core": "4.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.1",
"@angular/http": "4.4.1",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.4.1",
"@angular/router": "4.4.1",
```

and started to getting following error.  Any idea what it might be?

> I see that some suggest adding `@angular/platform-browser/animations` but also figured out that it is in `@angular/animations` now on.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: No provider for AnimationEngine!
Error: No provider for AnimationEngine!
at Error (native)
at injectionError (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:1533:90)
at noProviderError (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:1571:12)
at ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:3013:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:3052:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:2984:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.get (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:2853:21)
at resolveNgModuleDep (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:9853:25)
at _callFactory (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:9931:73)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (C:\Source\vsts\myusername\DefaultCollection\MyFolder\MyProject.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:9867:26)
```

in my **app.module.browser.ts**

```
// ...
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        // ...
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    // ...
})

// ...
```

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: Downgrade your angular to 4.3.x. There's currently no support for 4.4.x right now.

Comment: Thanks @Edric already downgraded to **4.3.6** and solved the issue

Comment: I'm not using material and 4.4.0-RC0 worked fine but 4.4.x now fails. What's changed? I can't find anything in the change log that would have caused this. Seems like a pretty large breaking change for a point release!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply downgrade your angular to 4.3.x as `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` has no support for 4.4.x:

```bash
npm install @angular/{animations,platform-browser,common,compiler,core,forms,http,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@~4.3.0 --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save-dev
```

Comment: I am getting the same error and I am on version 4.3.x. Any ideas?

Comment: @Silthus What version of `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` are you using?

Comment: both have the version `2.0.0-beta.10`

Comment: Did you install `@angular/animations`? Did you make sure you imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule`?

Comment: Yes I did install the animations package and I am using the corrent module imports. Also clearing the npm_modules folder did not help.

Comment: I was getting this error when deployed to production but not in development when using `4.3.6` and `2.0.0-beta.10`. I removed the tilde and caret symbols (i.e `"^4.3.6"` and `"~4.3.6"`) in `package.json` and then the production deployment worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this. I added BrowserAnimationsModule as Edric suggested and it worked.